# How to use the eclipse Jar-in-Jar Classloader in a non-eclipse project to load jars at runtime?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath, dependency-management

Eclipse allows in their export dialog to package the `.jar` files that a project depends on into a single resulting jar. Here you can see a example result:
[image: Screenshot of the inside of a example jar.]

How can I, as a non-eclipse user, take advantage of this functionality? In my case I **must load jar files dynamically from the classpath into the classpath at runtime** (I am creating an all-platform SWT application), so this technology would be perfect for me.

I already checked out all projects on maven central in the package `org.eclipse.jdt`, but none of the projects contains the relevant classes.

Is there a project somewhere that I can use to do this, as a non-eclipse user, and also in a non-jar (dev environment) context?

Answer (score 0):

Look at One-Jar:  http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/

I used it for a bit, but found I could not easily use it for web start applications.

Comment: Could you please add a code snipped for instructions on how to load a jar to the classpath at runtime? The project is very old and there is no documentation for usage like this.

Comment: Perhaps you just need to learn to use URLClassLoader in the standard runtime?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html